# On the Spectrum of $-\Delta+V$ and the Image of $V$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, quantum-mechanics

Both the fundamental examples of Schrodinger Operators (Harmonic Oscillator, Hydrogen Atom ones) and the physical intuition suggests that the discrete spectrum of $-\Delta+V$ is always a subset of the Image of $V$.
Is this true? And how is it proven? Is it linked with the spectrum of the multiplication operator by $V$ being the aforementioned image?
Referencies are much appreciated.
Thank you.

Edit: an answer showed me this is generally false, but the example is not on the whole $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ . I am interested in knowing if this is true in that case. I apologize for having omitted that detail.

Edit2: this question is stupid. I keep asking the wrong thing (and the above stated questions are easily answered as false). What I want to know is whether the discrete spectrum of $-\Delta+V$ on the whole $\mathbb{R}^d$ is a subset of $[\inf{V}, \sup{V}]$

Comment: The simplest counter-example is to look at $-\Delta + 0$ on $L^2(S^1)$. The spectrum is $\{(2\pi n)^2\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Does it change if I only consider my question on the whole $\R^{d}$?

Comment: If you look at a finite potential well $V(x) = \begin{cases}0 & |x|≤ L \\ 1 |x|>L\end{cases}$ you have bound states of energy less than $1$ (but larger than $0$) - the calculation should be in any beginners book on QM. If $V$ is bounded from below by some constatn $a$ (this is necessary for stability) you can use positivity of $-\Delta$ to find that $\sigma( - \Delta +V) \subseteq [a, \infty)$.

Comment: Oh yes. My question is dumb hahaha. Thanks a lot. I mean, I keep misstating what I need to know. The real thing I need to know is whether the discrete spectrum (if present) is contained in the interval $[\inf{V}, \sup{V}]$ in the $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ case.

Comment: I think so - there are some unrigorous physical arguments you can make about solutions of $-\Delta \psi = f\cdot \psi$ (with $f>c$ for some constant) having the freedom to explore everything in $\Bbb R^n$ (like plane waves) hence there being no normalisable solutions. But I couldn't quite turn them into a real argument. At any rate there are some powerful theorems of  the type: if $V(x)\to0$ as $\|x\|\to\infty$ with sufficient speed then any eigenvalue of $-\Delta + V$ is $≤0$.

Comment: If you combine that with all eigenvalues being $≥\inf V$ you get your result, provided $V$ has sufficient decay. See eg http://www.math.caltech.edu/SimonPapers/5.pdf for examples of "sufficient decay"

Comment: Thanks for the answers. So if $\lim_{r\to +\infty}V(r)=c$, can I conclude that if the potential $W=V-c$ satisfies the hypoteses in the main theorem of the paper, then $-\Delta+V$ does not have eigenvalues greater than $c$?

Comment: Also, can you tell me more about the fact that all eigenvalues are greater than $\inf V$? Thanks